# Asus Laptop has touchpad but Windowsw 10 does not list it in the device manager

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting, touchpad, asus-laptop

I have a Windows 10 Laptop recently purchased (ASUS VivoBook 15 X512FA) were I reinstalled windows 10 to remove the crapware. The touchpad is suddenly not working now. I tried the usual steps to fix this problem but the laptop does not seem to recognize that there is a trackpad.

does not list the trackpad in devices

[image]

Trackpad is not listed anywhere in the device manager (yes I have selected show hidden devices)
[image]

So even though I have found the [appropriate driver](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/DriversForWin10/TouchPad/Touchpad_DCH_ASUS_Win10_64_VER110032.zip) I cannot install it because windows 10 does not think the computer has a trackpad. How can I make the trackpad work?

*Notes*

- If you have any questions please ask
- The site with the drivers is here https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-15-X512FA/HelpDesk_Download/
- Bios for the laptop
  [image]

Comment: Access BIOS/UEFI (Firmware) and check if it's listed there as one of the devices among others like LAN/Audio/BT etc and see if it's enabled therein.

Comment: What should I see? Can you give me an example screen shot?

Comment: I do not have this laptop and every Firmware setup (BIOS/UEFI) is different. After you access your Firmware Setup, go thru each and every screen/options and see if there are any on-board devices listed just in case and if they are enabled and/or if there's an option to enable/disable them. Touchpad might be named as Internal Pointing Device

Comment: Ya I know that but I am trying to help someone with this issue (remotely due to COVID-19). I am not familiar with what a typical bios firmware screen looks like.

Comment: It is reasonable to surmise that the touchpad went defective.  I am not sure whether this is part of the keyboard or a separate device plugged into the motherboard

Comment: Okay I went through the BIOS Internal Pointing Device is Enabled. What other settings should I be looking for?

Comment: You would need to use the ASUS driver for your specific model.

Comment: Yes I found the ASUS driver needed added bios picture above for more details.

Comment: Some Asus Laptops have Function + F9 to toggle Enabling/Disabling Touchpad. Just make sure that such keys were not accidentally pressed. However ideally it should not cause the device to disappear from Device Manager. Just disable in BIOS boot to Windows, again access BIOS and enable the same & see if it has any effect. If possible try running some Live Linux Distro or some Windows Rescue disks based on Windows 10 PE off USB and see if Touchpad works. Basic drivers should ideally work. Vendor specific drivers enhanced functionality like 3 finger touch or 2 finger scroll etc.

Comment: If various try-outs do not help then it may be possible that the touchpad has become defective or may be the FFC that generally connects devices like Keyboard/Touchpad to rest of the board might have come lose. Did it work during the Windows 10 clean installation?